# Sum values that match a given condition AND create a new data frame (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like this:

where Age goes from 0 to 85+

```
|State    |Age    |2011   | 2012  | 2013  |2014|2015|2016|2017|2018|2019|
|:--------|-------|-------|-------|-------|----|----|----|----|----|----|
|Midwest  |0      |50,000 |33,000 |25,000 |  # |  # |  # |  # |  # |  # |
|Midwest  |1      |25,000 |2,000  |12,000 |  # |  # |  # |  # |  # |  # |
|Midwest  |2      |2,000  |25,000 |25,000 |  # |  # |  # |  # |  # |  # |
|.........|.......|.......|.......|.......|....|....|....|....|....|....|
|South    |0      |33,000 |12,000 |2,000  |  # |  # |  # |  # |  # |  # |
|South    |1      |12,000 |25,000 |33,000 |  # |  # |  # |  # |  # |  # |
```

I want to sum up the values by State, but only for those aged 18 and over.

I don't want just a sum or a groupby, but need to have a new data frame.

The output would look like this:

```
|State    |Age    |2011      |2012   |2013
|---------|-------|----------|-------|------
|Midwest  |18+    |700,000   | #     |
|South    |18+    |5,455,000 | #     |
|Northeast|18+    |34,000    | #     |
```

I have tried a few codes, but none really work...

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace values to numeric for all columns without first 2 columns:

```
print (df)
     State  Age    2011    2012    2013
0  Midwest    0  50,000  33,000  25,000
1  Midwest   20  25,000   2,000  12,000
2  Midwest   22   2,000  25,000  25,000
3    South   50  33,000  12,000   2,000
4    South    1  12,000  25,000  33,000

cols = df.columns[2:]
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(',','', regex=True).astype(int)

print (df)
     State  Age   2011   2012   2013
0  Midwest    0  50000  33000  25000
1  Midwest   20  25000   2000  12000
2  Midwest   22   2000  25000  25000
3    South   50  33000  12000   2000
4    South    1  12000  25000  33000
```

Then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) for greater or equal, set new values in column `Age` and aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = (df[df['Age'].ge(18)]
          .assign(Age = '18+')
          .groupby(['State','Age'], as_index=False)
          .sum())
print (df1)
     State  Age   2011   2012   2013
0  Midwest  18+  27000  27000  37000
1    South  18+  33000  12000   2000
```